# Dropdown values are not loading after the API call

Tags: angular, angular6

In my application I am getting the values of the dropdown from the API call. I assume that before the API call the dropdown is loading and it is not getting the values. but if I try the same option to print on the div tag I am getting the values.

Here is the Code:

```html
       <div *ngFor="let metricData of responseDropDownDataVal">
          <p>{{metricData.name}}</p>
       </div>

       <select #select1 bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricData"  data-selected-text-format="static" title="Select Volumes">
          <option *ngFor="let metricData of responseDropDownDataVal" >{{metricData.name}} 
          </option>
       </select>
```

This is my http get method for responseDropDownDataVal:

```js
  this.http.get(environment.envUrl + '/cloudWatch/dropDownForMetrics?' + params, { headers }).subscribe(data => {
    this.responseDropDownData = data;
    console.log("Drop Down Data");
    this.responseDropDownDataVal = this.responseDropDownData.data;
    console.log(this.responseDropDownDataVal);  
  },
```

can someone please suggest where my code is wrong I am getting the values on the paragraph tag but not on the dropdown

[image: select box]

Comment: your api is taking time to respond ??

Comment: i assume before the API call the dropdown is loading. but in the paragraph tag im getting the values when the component loads.

Comment: Where you calling API..?? Try to call api on ngOnInit()

Comment: im calling API on ngOnit() only @AniketAvhad

Comment: Can you show the response from the API call and also how you are declaring `metricData` in your component please?

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/DNfP8Ag)
This is the response i am getting
`           responseDropDownData: any;
            responseDropDownDataVal = [];     `
this is how i declared the values

Comment: the response of the API is bit delayed i guess that is the problem.
by the time the API loads the data Angular Components loads and also the Dropdown values.
is there any possible way where i can refresh the Dropdown value after i get a response form the API. @Nick

Comment: `<select #select1 bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricData.name"  data-selected-text-format="static" title="Select Volumes">
          <option *ngFor="let metricData of responseDropDownDataVal" >{{metricData.name}} 
          </option>
       </select>`

Comment: Remove `[(ngModel)]="metricData"`. Then Check what happen?

Comment: checked that too but still i am not getting the values. @A.Sakkeer

Comment: I still want to see how you declare `metricData` in the component.

Comment: Try `[selected]=true` or `[selected]="responseDropDownDataVal[0].name"`  in your **option** tag

Answer (score 0):

I think when you create selects with ngModel, you need to also use ngValue on the option like so:

```
<select #select1 bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricData"  data-selected-text-format="static" title="Select Volumes">
   <option 
       [ngValue]="metricData.name"
       *ngFor="let metricData of responseDropDownDataVal" >
       {{metricData.name}} 
   </option>
```

Please then try separating out the two way binding:

```
[ngModel]="metricData" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

And then

```
onChange(value) {
    this.metricData = value;
}
```

Comment: i used the ngValue too but still i am not getting the values.
is there any alternative way in which i can get the values or refresh the dropdown values after loading the component?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're seeing.  Are you seeing the options created in the select? Are you just not getting the value set in the component?

Comment: Ohhhh.... you need to not make the name of your ngModel the same as the variable in your loop. Try `let metricDataOption of responseDropDownDataVal` and then `metricDataOption.name`

Comment: i checked with changing the ngModel value aslo im not seeing any data

Comment: im not getting the value set in the component in dropdown but i am getting the same values in the paragraph tag @Nick

Comment: `<select #select1 bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricData"  data-selected-text-format="static" title="Select Volumes">
            <option *ngFor="let metricDataOption of responseDropDownDataVal"  >{{metricDataOption.name}} </option>
            

          </select>`
i updated the code too

Comment: Your code still doesn't have `ngValue` in the option tag

Comment: `<option 
            [ngValue]="metricData.name" 
            *ngFor="let metricDataOption of responseDropDownDataVal"  >
            {{metricDataOption.name}} 
          </option>`
sorry i have added this before but forgot to copy. Again i don't see any values at the dropdown

Comment: change the ngValue property to [ngValue]="metricDataOption.name"

Comment: on the page refresh the data populating in the paragraph tag is bit delay by the time this container is loading. i assume the new values obtained from the API call taking time, by the time time the container and the dropdown values are loaded. @Sachi.Dila @Nick
`<select bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricData"  data-selected-text-format="static" title="Select Volumes">
            <option 
            [ngValue]="metricDataOption.name" 
            *ngFor="let metricDataOption of responseDropDownDataVal"  >
            {{metricDataOption.name}} 
          </option>
</select>`

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Please try the second step also

Comment: Also please try removing the bootstrap attributes to find out if that is affecting it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see,

```
  <select #select1 bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricData" data-selected-text-format="static" title="Select Volumes">
       <option [ngValue]="metricDataOption.name" *ngFor="let metricDataOption of responseDropDownDataVal" > {{metricDataOption.name}} 
       </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: on the page refresh the data populating in the paragraph tag is bit delay by the time this container is loading. i assume the new values obtained from the API call taking time, by the time time the container and the dropdown values are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   import { BootstrapSelectDirective } from './../bootstrap-select.directive';
   @ViewChild(BootstrapSelectDirective)
    bootstrapSelectDirective: BootstrapSelectDirective;

      this.http.get(environment.envUrl + '/cloudWatch/dropDownForMetrics?' + params, { headers }).subscribe(data => {
      this.responseDropDownData = data;
      console.log("Drop Down Data");
      this.responseDropDownDataVal = this.responseDropDownData.data;
      console.log(this.responseDropDownDataVal);
      this.loadCloudWatchVolumeGraph(this.responseDropDownDataVal[0]);
      this.bootstrapSelectDirective.refresh();
    },
```

As the data for the dropdown was loading after the component was loading i refreshed the bootstrapSelectDirective now the dropdown loads the data